# Ошибка при сбросе пароля django

Tags: python, django, email

подскажите в чем проблема. Делал сброс пароля но в емаиле который приходит не ссылка а не шаблонизированый html.

вот файл.html с сообщением на почту:

```
Someone asked for password reset for email {{ email }}. Follow the link
below:
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url "password_reset_confirm" uidb64=uid
token=token %}
Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.get_username }}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

вместо нормальной ссылки приходит это:
[http://127.0.0.1:8000{%](http://127.0.0.1:8000%7B%) url "password_reset_confirm" uidb64=uid token=token %}

Comment: покажите результат `message = loader.render_to_string("your_email_template.html", your_context)`